# When is absence of evidence not evidence of absence?

Tags: epistemology

"Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence."

I think this statement raises some kind of epistemic problem.  Like, how are we supposed to conclude the potential non-existence of something, like Santa Claus or dragons?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89379/discussion-on-question-by-vorpal-professor-absence-of-evidence-is-not-evidence-o).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I think the distinction is that people often conflate "negative obervations" with "absence of evidence".

To take the Santa example - if you simply declared "I have no evidence that Santa exists, therefore he does not exist", then you would be arguing from an absence of evidence.

However, if you said "Santa is said to travel in a flying sleigh, and no radar returns consistent with such a vehicle have ever been observed" then this is *not* an absence of evidence. This is a hypothesis (namely, that Santa flies around the world in his sleigh) from which we can make a prediction (that the sleigh would be visible on radar) and then we make an observation that the predicted scenario does not arise.

This is a negative observation - it's not an absence of evidence, it's *evidence* that our hypothesis may be incorrect.

Of course, you could argue that the sleigh is magically hidden from radar by the pixie dust mixed into its paintwork, but at some point Occam's Razor kicks in and reminds you that the simplest explanation for a negative observation is that the thing you were expecting to see simply doesn't exist.

Comment: I think this is morally right, but unfortunately there is no clear separation between ["negative evidence" and absence of evidence](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Negative_evidence#Fallacy). It is usually said that absence of evidence *is* evidence of absence if the presence should be expected to produce evidence, if true. However, this does not work for idle unfalsifiable speculations, like Santa. One can always say that Santa is magical, and is not supposed to register on radars, or that the sleigh is metaphorical. In such cases the issue is burden of proof, not negative evidence.

Comment: Better evidence of Santa's absence would be something more like the computation of the fuel requirements of travelling that fast, and the limited quantity of fuel in the world.  To make the lack of observations into a contradiction, one would need to prove we have adequate coverage that an object moving that fast would be observed.  But the fact it is moving that fast, and all our radar and sonar are designed for things moving slower might be the very reason it would not be observed.

Comment: I agree with Conifold's observation that there is no clear separation. The Santa example is not typical, because we have plenty of evidence that Santa does not exist in that the things attributed to him would violate the laws of nature. In more general cases, it is not so clear. For example, in the 1990s some astronomers conjectured the existence of a second star in our solar system, but twenty years on and we have not found it despite looking. This is not conclusive proof, but the absence of evidence for it is evidence against there being such a thing.

Comment: What if someone doesn't believe that Occam's Razor is a useful rule of thumb?

Comment: @probably_someone, it's probably because they have escaped the Matrix.

Comment: @elliotsvensson But seriously, a lot of conspiracy theorists, young-Earth creationists, and flat-earther types explicitly reject Occam's Razor. Arguments based on it simply fail to be convincing for them, and there doesn't appear to be a good way to demonstrate to them that Occam's Razor is a good rule of thumb.

Comment: @probably_someone, it's a good heuristic, but it's not the only heuristic.  I have been led to believe that plausibility, explanatory scope, and explanatory power have seats at the table together with Occam's razor, though I acknowledge that some folks dispute that.

Comment: @probably_someone, why do you suppose that young-Earth creationists in particular might want to reject Occam's razor?

Comment: @probably_someone: for instance, I think that Occam's razor might be aligned against the Cosmological Principle, not in favor of it, based on the evidence.

Comment: @elliotsvensson Well yeah, the whole point of a heuristic is that it's a guiding principle, not a strict rule. It's not meant to rule out hypotheses but to suggest an order of evaluation, favoring the simple before moving to the complex. I suppose some people do take it too far, though.

Comment: @elliotsvensson Young-Earth creationism posits that the Earth was created 6,000 years ago by God and that evolution doesn't happen. Every day, we find more and more evidence of rocks that are billions of years old and organisms that are nearly as old whose lineages evolve through time. In order to keep the original assumptions, more must be added: either 1) there is a conspiracy among scientists and academics to lie in a completely self-consistent way about what evidence they've collected, which is getting bigger and more elaborate every day; or (continued on next comment)

Comment: @elliotsvensson 2) The world was intentionally created to resemble _so precisely_ a world that is billions of years old with evolving organisms that are hundreds of millions of years old that it is impossible for scientists to see through the trick. The trick has to get more and more elaborate with each new piece of evidence that is found. Meanwhile, the most plausible theory by Occam's Razor would be that the Earth is billions of years old and that organisms evolve. It explains the evidence without having to add extra assumptions about a conspiracy or a trick.

Comment: @elliotsvensson "I think that Occam's razor might be aligned against the Cosmological Principle, not in favor of it, based on the evidence." What evidence are you referring to?

Comment: @elliotsvensson The (vague) idea that "things are different farther away" is contradicted by the fact that the cosmic microwave background is incredibly uniform, everywhere and every time we look, to within one part in 100,000.

Comment: @probably_someone, I second-guessed myself and deleted the comment.  I'll reproduce it now: The Cosmological Principle would have us interpret redshift as implying dark matter and dark energy.  But the evidence could more simply be interpreted that things are different farther away.

Comment: @probably_someone, I don't mean, "things look different the farther you look" but "things are different the farther you get from here" (...as a simpler interpretation of the evidence than redshift + Cosmological principle + dark energy/matter)

Comment: @elliotsvensson Is that really simpler, though? Where "here" is in relation to the rest of the universe is constantly changing, since the Earth, Sun, and Milky Way are all moving, and not in straight lines, either. Are you saying that the hypothesis, "the fundamental laws of physics in distant parts of the universe change constantly to account for the position of a particular rocky planet around a particular type-G main sequence star on the outer edge of a particular spiral galaxy" is simpler than "there's some matter and energy that we don't know about yet"?

Comment: @probably_someone, "there's some matter and energy that we don't know about yet" is a big deal.

Comment: @elliotsvensson Indeed it is. Yet an even bigger and more problematic deal would be to assert that the fundamental laws of physics are dependent on position, because this assumption directly contradicts other assumptions we have made throughout physics. For example, general relativity assumes that the laws of physics are the same in every reference frame; this could not be true if the laws of physics depended on position. Also, the conservation of energy, momentum, and angular momentum are based on the fact that the laws of physics don't change with time, position, or orientation.

Comment: @elliotsvensson There have been many tests of general relativity even at extreme distances (for example, the rate of slowdown of the rotation rate of pulsars matches GR predictions, and the detection of gravitational waves from black hole mergers millions of light years away is another confirmation), and even more tests of the basic conservation laws at extreme distances (for example, accurately describing the kinematics of star clusters, and also noting that stars, which depend on a delicate energy balance for their existence, look basically the same everywhere).

Comment: @elliotsvensson In order to make physics self-consistent again after breaking everything like that, while still explaining all the evidence, you have to make fundamental physics _much_ less simple. You have to specify _how_ the laws of physics vary with position (and by extension, time), which means turning basically every constant that we have measured into a function dependent on position and time that can vary in an infinite number of ways. We then have to justify _which particular_ way each of those functions vary, which requires more assumptions.

Comment: @elliotsvensson And all of this added complexity has the payoff of... not explaining the evidence any better than simply suggesting that there's some currently-invisible matter and energy out there. It's not like that hasn't happened in the past: for most of the 20th century, particle physicists spent entire careers discovering new bits of matter that we didn't know about before. The fact that the _most_ plausible explanation for the bizarre things we're seeing is the idea that there's a lot of invisible matter out there makes this a _very_ exciting time to be in the field.

Comment: Radar returns from a wooden sleigh, a team of reindeer, a man, and some sacks of plastic toys at height would be negligible. Designers of stealth-aircraft technology would be envious of such a system.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89428/discussion-on-answer-by-anaximander-absence-of-evidence-is-not-evidence-of-absen).

Answer (score 33):

Elliot Sober offers a useful argument on this :

> "Absence of evidence isn't evidence of absence" is a slogan that is
>    popular among scientists and nonscientists alike. ...
>
> There has been some philosophical work on the motto that doesn't use a
>    probability framework and it provides a good way of isolating the problem I want to
>    address. Here are two example arguments from Douglas Walton's insightful 1996
>    book, Arguments from Ignorance:
>
> > **I do not have any** evidence that it is raining here and now.
> >
> > It is not raining here and now.
> >
> > **I do not have any** evidence that there is a storm on the surface of Jupiter now.
> >      There is no storm on the surface of Jupiter now.
>
> Though neither argument is deductively valid, it is easy to see how each can be
>    turned into a valid argument by adding a premise. The arguments have the form:
>
> > **I do not have any** evidence that p is true.
> >
> > p is false.
>
> Just add the premise
>
> > (P1) If p were true, then I'd have evidence that p is true.
>
> This further premise may be true in the case of the rain. Suppose, as in Walton's
>    example, that I am sitting in a house with a tin roof and that I'd hear the
>    characteristic pitter-patter if rain were falling. It is easy to imagine that the extra
>    premise Pi is false in the case of the storm on Jupiter; suppose, instead, that
>
> > (P2)If p were true, then I'd have no evidence that p is true.
>
> The Jupiter example is enough to show that the motto "absence of evidence isn't
>    evidence of absence" is sometimes true and the rain example is enough to show that
>    it is sometimes false. This is because P2 is true of some propositions in some
>    circumstances and the same goes for P1. So let us agree that absence of evidence
>    does not logically entail that you have evidence of absence. And let us also agree
>    that there are situations in which absence of evidence is evidence of absence. What more is there to say about the motto than this ? (Elliott Sober, 'Absence of Evidence and Evidence of Absence',  Philosophical Studies: An International Journal for Philosophy in the Analytic
>   Tradition, Vol. 143, No. 1, Models, Methods, and Evidence: Topics in the Philosophy of
>   Science. Proceedings of the 38th Oberlin Colloquium in Philosophy (Mar., 2009), pp. 63-90: 64.)

Sober goes on to explore cases in which P1 and P2 are both false. This produces interesting nuances but the quotation above should give you a sound *basic* assessment of the statement.

Comment: `I do not have evidence that it is raining here and now` , does it mean that `I have evidence that it is not raining here and now, and my evidence is that I do not have evidence that it is raining here and now`? Can the absence of evidence sometimes be itself the evidence of the opposite? Thank you

Comment: The problem here, is that I can assert that the fact that I don't have evidence that it is raining here and now, does not contribute to the evidence that the opposite is the case,  and the evidence for the opposite is the fact that I do not see rain and that the world is dry here and now.

Comment: Hi ! I can't see that 'I do not have (any) evidence that it is raining here and now' means 'I have evidence that it is not raining here and now'. I can't see that Sober intends this. Any answer is a target for any number of arrows - I appreciate that and it's just as it should be. I was only trying to put the OP in square 1 of an analysis and appraisal of the slogan.

Comment: So, I misunderstood the answer, thank you Geoffrey +1 !

Comment: @SmootQ. It happens to us all ;)- You are a really welcome new presence on PSE. I already look out your answers and comments. High quality. Best - Geoffrey

Comment: thank you so much, I decided to start studying philosophy and logic on my own a year ago, and I came here as the best way to digest what I learn is by looking into others' questions  Best ! - Taqi

Comment: Although I am still bad at knowing which philosopher thinks what?! I have a very difficult time memorizing this kind of historical information, I am more oriented to ideas themselves.

Answer (score 10):

Go into your kitchen. Is there an elephant? In this case, absence of evidence *is* evidence of absence. You know that if there was an elephant, you would have evidence. No evidence, no elephant.

But is there a mouse? It is quite possible that there is a mouse but no evidence.

So you need to decide two things: How likely is it a priori that a statement is true? And how likely is it that there would be no evidence if the statement was true? From these two you can figure out how likely the statement is false if there is no evidence.

Comment: A robot or a baby wouldn't be able to gauge how likely a statement is to be true, though.  Does that mean the reasoning is flawed?

Comment: @elliotsvensson If the reasoning is flawed, I guess that means you have no way of knowing that there isn't an elephant in your kitchen.

Comment: But what ratio should we assign the prior probability of an elephant in my suburban California kitchen?  1 in a billion?  1 in a trillion?  It's impossible to be sure!

Comment: I'm playing Devil's advocate: there's no difficulty in assigning such probabilities because they get "canceled out" when you divide by other probabilities that you also assign.  I don't have to know "0.0000343 % of the time", I just have to know that "A is one in a trillion, but B is one in five trillion, for Pete's sake".

Comment: This is wrong. It's pure math. An Elephant is by definition a certain size, and visible. It takes up space. A kitchen only has so much space, and one can determine that the volume of space visible to you, which has no elephant, is complete proof that no elephant exist in the kitchen. Assuming of course you are talking about a real elephant. A mouse however takes up significantly less space, and you can not determine with a quick glance, if a mouse may occupy any of the small spaces that you have no visual of. If it was in a shoe box, you'd have proof, like with the elephant in the kitchen.

Comment: This is actually a brilliant answer, but it needs work. The a priori and pos-hoc test is exactly what is the philosophical distinction that the answer @anaximander wrote alludes to, but doesn't spell out.

Comment: Absence of elephants?

Comment: This is correct and nicely short. Would you mind working in the aspect (mentioned in another answer constinsting of a giant quote) of `If p were true, then I'd have evidence that p is true.` in a *slightly* more explicit way?

Comment: @KjetilNordin This is just a bad example - a better one would be a fork and a mouse - as they're of similar size - but both are usually hidden.  You usually assume there's a fork in a friends kitchen though; but not a mouse.

Comment: The fork has a problem: It would be most likely in my cutlery drawer or my dish washer. Even though it's more likely that there is a fork than a mouse in my kitchen, if I can't find either after a reasonable search, then I am more sure about the absence of a fork than the absence of the mouse. Because mice are known to hide, forks are not.

Comment: So, if God is larger than an elephant, and is in my kitchen... There would be no room for me, or anything else. We have arrived at Nonduality. "*There is no reality but God, there is only God*" - Rumi. Is Mathematics in my kitchen? How would I be able to tell? Hmm

Answer (score 7):

A better phrase is "absence of proof is not proof of absence". One definition of "evidence" is that E is evidence for H if seeing E justifies a Bayesian update that increases the probability assigned to H. And if all the relevant probabilities are in the open interval (0,1), then E being evidence for H under this definition means that (not E) is evidence for (not H); that is, the posterior probability of (not H) increases when one sees (not E).

However, the amount by which the posterior for (not H) increases on seeing (not E) can be arbitrarily small, even when keeping constant the amount by which the posterior for H increases on seeing E. For instance, seeing one white raven proves that there exists a white raven, but seeing one black raven is only a tiny bit of evidence that no white ravens exist.

And in many contexts, people use "evidence" to mean not merely something that increases the posterior by any amount, but something that increases the posterior by a significant amount. By this definition of "evidence", absence of evidence often isn't evidence of absence. But there certainly are cases where even by this more restrictive definition, absence of evidence is indeed evidence of absence. For instance, in poker, if someone folds in a situation where, if they had a royal flush, they could reveal it and win, that is rather strong evidence that they don't have a royal flush. If the victim of a robbery says they stabbed the robber, and a suspect doesn't have any stab wounds, that is evidence they aren't the robber.

Comment: combine with answer with the one @gnasher gave and you have a complete statement. Bayes is indeed the mathematical answer to the probability question.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a real standard of proof, like observation, or constructive demonstration, it only exists when it exists, not when it would be annoying or problematic for it not to exist.  Annoyances and problems, particularly paradoxes, are part of reality.

In classical logic that results in the truism that you cannot prove an assertion that is 'truly negative' in quality.  You cannot know that unicorns don't exist, only that they are highly unlikely. You cannot get rid of God via any proof.

You can rule out 190-degree planar triangles, but only via proof that they would change the nature of geometry, not because you haven't found any.  And then you can find geometry that has this nature: one where planes are interchanged with spheres, and it turns out to be useful to investigate those.

Maybe an example from non-classical logic, one with a slightly different epistemology, will help.  This is a principle in the Intuitionist interpretation of mathematics to a much higher degree than it is in classical logic.

From the Intuitionist point of view, evidence of absence would be constructive proof that any instance would result in a contradiction with other principles.

So, we have a proof -- the 'hairy ball theorem' that a smooth vector flow on a sphere does not exist.  If we found such a thing, it would necessarily destroy its own construction logically.

But there is still an absence of evidence for an actual discontinuity, given any given vector field.  We cannot necessarily locate it by constructively interrogating the vector field itself.  When we can't, we should not act as though it exists or does not exist.

Clearly this is not evidence for the absence of the discontinuity, because we know that the field cannot be smooth unless the system itself is inconsistent.  It does in some sense exist, but not in a sense that we should take seriously, and not in a way that we can safely act upon.  Because there is in fact a possibility that there is an eventual inconsistency in our accumulated reasoning.

Comment: "Eventual Inconsistency" is a beautiful phrase, like "Slow Catastrophe" or something.

Answer (score 2):

Like many such statements, it's only *roughly* true... but only for certain types of argument.

For instance, if we have an argument like this:

```
If A (we have evidence) then B.
A (we have evidence).
Therefore B.
```

This is the classic Modus Ponens, and in this type of argument lacking evidence does not mean evidence of lack.

Consider Modus Tollens however:

```
If A then B (we have evidence).
Not B (we have no evidence)
Therefore not A.
```

In this form it is logically true that absence of evidence is in fact evidence of absence.

The question then becomes whether the Modus Tollens formulation is in fact *sound* for the specific subjects.

I can for instance say:

```
If it is raining then my car will be wet.
My car is not wet.
Therefore it is not raining.
```

While this looks fine, it lacks enough detail to be *sound*.  If I check my car and find it dry *because it is in my garage* then that doesn't prove that it is not raining.  The logic is valid but the initial premise is not sound, so the argument fails.  In this case absence of evidence for rain does not constitute evidence of absence.

But how about this similar argument:

```
If it is raining on my car then my car will be wet.
My car is not wet.
Therefore it is not raining on my car.
```

Now I am fully justified in claiming that absence of evidence is in fact evidence of absence.  My car is not wet, therefore it is not raining on my car.  This is both valid and sound.

We may be able to make similar arguments about dragons or Santa Claus.  Testing the soundness of those arguments might take some doing however.  We'd need a starting premise that was much more compelling than `If dragons existed then we would have unambiguous evidence of their existence.`

Establishing the soundness of the initial premise is potentially impossible.  In some cases you will run up against someone who simply modifies the definition of their preferred thing to avoid any possibility of a sound logical argument against it.  Can't see a dragon?  That's because it's invisible.  And intangible.  And doesn't react to any of your senses or any possible detection apparatus you can propose.  Doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Which I suspect is a large part of the reason why we generally accept that absence of evidence is not in fact evidence of absence.

Comment: If you can't win the game, just change the rules. Clever.

Comment: @ScottRowe I don't think I changed any rules here, I explained that whether or not the absence of evidence is valid grounds to conclude evidence of absence is dependent on the claims being made.

Comment: Not yourself, I was referring to evasions like: "*Can't see a dragon? That's because it's invisible.*" We used to call that moving the goalposts.

Comment: @ScottRowe Ah, yeah. Moving the goal posts is an old and very common tactic to avoid having to admit they're wrong.

Answer (score 2):

1. An *absence of something* is different than an *evidence of something*, that's clear.
2. You imply that *an evidence proves "something"*. Acceptable. Evidence of rain proves that the air has a high humidity.
3. But *a non-evidence is not necessarily the proof of the opposite of "something"*. An absence of rain does not prove that the air humidity is low. Formally, you are *affirming the consequent* with your suggestion to prove something by not having an evidence.
4. So, you cannot "conclude the potential non-existence of something" by not having an evidence.

No relation with epistemology. Just a fallacious interpretation of a useless cliché, like:

*"The cliché of an absence is not the absence of a cliché" does not mean that the presence of a cliché implies the presence a cliché of non-absence (or a non-cliché of abscence).*

Answer (score 0):

This is the Contrapositive
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition

In your statement "absence of evidence is not evidence of absence", we can write it formally as
x -> y where

(x) = absence of evidence
(y) = not evidence of absence

The truth table can be written as (!x || y) (not x or y)

Let's assume y is true (no proof of absence)

If y is true (we have no evidence of absence) then the absence of evidence doesn't matter, the answer is still true.
If y is not true (we have evidence of absence) then this can only be correct if x is true (there is absence of evidence).

Comment: I wonder if the "is" would not be better symbolized as "<=>", if and only if. Welcome to Philosophy!

Comment: That would be a good distinction, thanks for the suggestion. I suppose this is a specification OP would need to define, it's hard to interpret thy question as asked. The accepted answer from anaximander suggest that "x therefore y" which would match the contrapositive definition. The truth table for "if and only if" would cause the statement "there is no evidence of absense" to be true only if we had a positive statement "there is absence of evidence" which is confusing too. It seems to make more sense if we change the sentence to only use positive statements.

Comment: Instead maybe it should be accurate to ask "is absence of evidence proof of evidence of absense"

Answer (score 0):

This is about burden of proof. If I say that God exists, the burden of proof is on me. The statement that there is no evidence that God does not exist is not evidence that God does not exist is not an argument for the existence of God. The burden of proof remains with me as with Russell's Teapot. For the avoidance of doubt of theists, atheism is not a belief system. It is simply the absence of belief in God. Atheists have no evidence that God does not exist nor do we believe that God does not exist. Belief is irrelevant to us. The burden of proof remains with the theist, or the believer in Santa Claus or orbiting teapots. Occam's Razor is good for cutting excess fat from confused thought.